# Join two tables on two dimensions without cross-joining

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table with IDs and domains(T1). Another with Names and domains(T2). A third with names and IDs (T3).

In its simplified form, my query goes as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM T2
LEFT JOIN T1 
ON T2.domain = T1.domain 
) 
LEFT JOIN T3
ON T1.name = T3.name
```

The output I'm looking for is a list with columns : "ID", "Name" and "Domain" where either domains or Names match in order to get the IDs. The challenge I face is that one domain can match with two names, and this creates a set of false positives (because the name matches, the wrong ID is also attributed).

Any best practices I should follow when doing these kind of joins would be most helpful.

Thanks 
S

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.domain, coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN
     T1 
     ON T2.domain = T1.domain LEFT JOIN
     T3
     ON T2.name = T3.name AND
        t1.domain IS NULL;  -- no match on T1
```

This matches on `domain` first.  Then if there is no `domain`-match, it uses `name`.